# Using post data from html textarea in php

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm just trying to get my `POST` data from an html textarea form using a php script, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't actually posting the data. I'm fairly certain all the syntax is right.

html : support.html

```
<form action = 'submit.php' method = 'post'>
First Name <input type = 'text'  name = 'firstname'><br><br>
Last Name <input type = 'text'  name = 'lastname'><br><br>
Email Address <input type = 'text'  name = 'email'><br><br>
Subject <input type = 'text'  name = 'subject'><br><br>
Details<br>
<textarea  name = 'details'  rows = '10' cols = '75'></textarea></br>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'Submit' value = 'Submit' >
</form>
```

php: submit.php

```
<?php
 /*

 Process user information

 */
 include 'init.php'; // connecting to mysql database 
 $success = false; // flag for whether all forms are filled out
 if (isset($_POST['details']))    
 {
 $details = $_POST['details'];
 echo "$details"; // checking to see what is in textarea
 }
 // more processing & mysql database work
  ?>
```

All the other form data is sending correctly. There is mysql database work that I don't show but it shouldn't interfere with how post data is being obtained right?

Comment: Could it be that in your example you don't actually set a text area value? as in `<textarea name="details">my value</textarea>`.

Comment: I just ran your exact code with test text in the text area field and it echo'd out the contents so your syntax is correct. Are these two files in the same directory?

Comment: @phpPhil No, I don't think it's that because I originally had a starting sentence in the textarea when I first wrote the code up, and I still had the problem. Plus, the html form I send always has user input in it for testing purposes.

Comment: @Matthew Yep, all other form data is fine. It's just the textarea.

Comment: It's working -_-, I tried adding starting text between the tags again and it ran. The name of my textarea tag was `body` initially, could that have affected it? @phpPhil

Comment: It shouldn't have - except if you had another form element with this name. in this case it could have overwritten the text area value in the POST.